# TFS Binding. What is its purpose?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I come from an SVN / GIT background and would consider myself quite converse with the workings of source control systems overall.

So imagine my surprise when moving a project to TFS I'm requested to "bind" my solution:

[image]

**I understand what I need to do to bind**, my question is:

- Why should I modify my .sln and .proj files to satisfy this?
- What purpose does binding provide?

I've searched MSDN and Google.  There is plenty explaining *how* but not **why**.

Comment: [What is a Source Control Binding?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/korbyp/archive/2003/08/20/54113.aspx)

Comment: It says right in the dialog box: It's for IDE integration.

Comment: SVN (for example AnkhSvn) also works without changing your .csproj and .sln files, isn't that what OP is asking?

Comment: @CodeCaster - Correct.  I'm dubious that I need to modify the code I'm checking in just for IDE integration.

Comment: You don't have to modify any "code". Only the .csproj/.sln files.

Answer (score 0):

There are source control plugins for various SCM tools, it just happens that you weren't using a plugin with your previous tool.

The plugins provide IDE integration. For example, it will show you if you've modified a file or not within the solution explorer, and give you a context menu with source control actions when you right-click on a file in the IDE.

Do you need to set up binding for your solution/projects? No. Does it hurt anything to do it? Also no. Do you get some extra useful functionality by doing it? Yes. There's no compelling reason *not* to do it, basically.

Comment: Daniel, you might want to elaborate on what the benefits are of how TFS does it, vs., say, SVN.